# how to see if a page on a pdf contains specific text

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to programtically find all pages in a PDF that contain a certain substring and if they do then I want to replace that page with another PDF. Replacing that page isn't a problem - I can do so with PHP's pdflib bindings or pdftk. What I don't know how to do is how to test to see if a page contains a certain text.

Any ideas?

Comment: depends on if the text is literally in pdf, or if the pdf's just an IMAGE of the text... the first case is easy to handle. the other one, not so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is splitting the PDF's on single pages with pdftk, then converting the content to text with [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/)’s pdftotext command, and searching the resulting text with PHP or grep.